# delete or update depending column value

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, I have a **product** table. It has **product_id** and **product_name** columns. and 
 I've a table **product_purchase**

```
pr_pur_id  product_id(FK)  pur_quantity
 1           170           6
 2           190           6
 3           270           0
 4           70            1
 5           10            6
 6           20            6
```

and I've a **product_sale** table. The Table has **pr_sale_id** , **product_id**(FK) and **sale_quantity** columns.
If I want to  insert  **product_sale** which **product_id** has already in **product_purchase** table, the **product_purchase.pr_pur_id** should delete if **product_purchase.pur_quantity** is 0. If the **product_purchase.pur_quantity** is more then 0 it will reduce depends on **product_sale.sale_quanity**.

How can I execute update or delete query depends on **product_purchase.pur_quantity** column?

Comment: You'll have to do that in your server-side (or client-side) code. As far as I know, there is no way to force mySQL to decide to perform an `UPDATE` or `DELETE`.

Comment: you can write a stored proc that check value and based on that takes decision to fire and update or delete query.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you, but I suspect either the `REPLACE` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` statements are what you're looking for.

Comment: It would help if you showed examples of of what you want to happen in various cases.

Comment: I agree with Barman, you probably can do the work with insert on duplicate key statment

Comment: produc_id is a column of product table

Comment: @Barmar . why I'll use REPLACE or INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE. . I need remove product in purchase list when it sell

Comment: Oh, I see. Every time you make a sale, you reduce the quantity in inventory, and when quantity goes to 0 you want to delete the row. I think the best way to do this is with a trigger.

Comment: yea. but I'm not expert in trigger, can u help @Barmar

Comment: i know basic in trigger

Comment: Neither am I, sorry. Why don't you try to figure it out by reading the documentation?

Comment: ok sir I'll try to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered simply leaving the row in there with a `0` available count? Then it acts as a historical record if you ever need to refer to this information later. The only real downside is that you'll need to filter those rows out in queries with a clause like `WHERE pur_quantity != 0`.

Comment: but extra records which pur_quanity=0 wiil never need in next time. why I'll keep junk records? will it disturb my database performance when extra record will big amount.

Comment: Are they junk records? You'll never, ever, ever want to know the history of your available products? How many rows are we talking about that it would affect performance noticeably? Even if there are a large number of records, I imagine that you could overcome this with good indexing.

Comment: ok sir, I understand and little bit worry.If you're right. my database should change. product_sale table column should pr_sale_id , product_pur_id(FK) and sale_quantity.(not product_id). and oh this software is for a big shoe shop. they have at least 5-10 thousands diffrent products. For purchase product report, my idea was collect  from sale table. may be that was not good idea. thank you.

Comment: Only you can determine that based on the needs of your client and the application. So maybe deleting them is the right thing to do; that's for your to determine. I was just pointing out that there's often value in keeping historical information, especially if the cost of doing so is small. On a side note, 5-10 thousand rows doesn't sound like a lot for a relational database. See this question for some more in depth information about what's "a lot" for a relational database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350581/how-many-rows-are-too-many-for-a-mysql-table.