# Firebase is good for database storage and retreival and other operations?

Tags: java, android, firebase, hosting, firebase-realtime-database

I'm planning to use Firebase to store around 2 to 3 lacks of Product links and access them via my Android application.

Is it good to go with Firebase?. Why i'm worried is regarding the DB query, we cant put LIKE clause and some other disadvantages related query is there.

One advantage i feel is, datastorage will be in Json format & hence the access will be much faster.

So, can you suggest what my understanding is right or not? also if i'm going in wrong path, can you please guide me the correct one.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a post that might help: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81349/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-firebase-for-a-database/82048

Comment: Hello, will there be any impact if i use sql database to query?, suppose if record count is in millions, does it impact the performance?

Comment: That all depends on 1) What database vendor you will use, 2) how you will design your table structures (e.g. indexes), 3) How you write your queries. Here is a post for MySQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5350581/how-many-rows-are-too-many-for-a-mysql-table